# how to refine this code mental block Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have these two methods that I would like to combine into one.  But for the life of me I can't see how. NOOB big time. any help appreciated.

```
  def is_active_no_category
      'active' if params[:category].blank?
  end


  def is_active(category)
      'active' if  params[:category] == category.name.parameterize
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the below function passing a `category` as an argument is optional. If you *do not* pass an argument it will work like your `is_active_no_category` method. If you *do* pass an argument. It will work like your `is_active` method.

```
def is_active(category = nil)
  'active' if (category.present? && params[:category] == category.name.parameterize) || (category.nil? && params[:category].blank?)
end
```

You may be able to make the `if` statement more compact, but you haven't stated the exact requirements for your function, so I gave you the most complete solution.